# Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to a product of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

Let $f, g_1, g_2:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and of bounded variation functions on $[a,b]$. Show that

$$\displaystyle \int_a^b fd(g_1g_2) = \displaystyle \int_a^b fg_1dg_2 + \displaystyle \int_a^b fg_2dg_1$$

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE. Please show us what you have attempted/what your thoughts on the problem are.

Comment: You can see the obvious analogy with the product rule of differentiation here. Even though you cannot assume these are differentiable functions, you should go back and examine the proof of that product rule. The same approximations in that proof will be useful here.